# Insert a custom row using drf-renderer-xlsx

Tags: django-rest-framework, xlsx, django-drf-renderer

I'm using `drf-renderer-xlsx` according of the [official doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#xlsx-binary-spreadsheet-endpoints).

The endpoint is ok and I can to export my data in xlsx format.

My problem is that I need to insert a custom row to my file. Someone has any idea?